Could not determine the dependencies of task ':expo-modules-core:compileDebugAidl'
Need to add functionality to add a quick-setting tile service (if possible a sticky notification using foreground service as well) to launch emergency trigger from lock-screen or any other screen in the Android OS (later we may plan for iOS as well).
Current Issue - During the creation of the Android bundle to change the native code using the command -
sudo npx expo run:android
We are getting the following error logs -
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':expo-modules-core:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':expo-modules-core:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1.
     Required by:
         project :expo-modules-core
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.13' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1'
           Constraint path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.13' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:{strictly 0.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 0.3.0
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.13' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.10' (debugVariantDefaultApiPublication) --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0'

   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:{strictly 0.3.0}.
     Required by:
         project :expo-modules-core
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.13' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1'
           Constraint path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.13' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:{strictly 0.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 0.3.0
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.13' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.10' (debugVariantDefaultApiPublication) --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0'

   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :expo-modules-core > com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.10
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.13' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1'
           Constraint path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.13' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:{strictly 0.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 0.3.0
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.13' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.10' (debugVariantDefaultApiPublication) --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0'


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 12s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
Error: /Users/nishant/Documents/Work/LHE-User-App/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: /Users/nishant/Documents/Work/LHE-User-App/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/nishant/Documents/Work/LHE-User-App/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (/Users/nishant/Documents/Work/LHE-User-App/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (/Users/nishant/Documents/Work/LHE-User-App/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (/Users/nishant/Documents/Work/LHE-User-App/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:52:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (/Users/nishant/Documents/Work/LHE-User-App/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/run/android/runAndroidAsync.js:36:24)

Desired Outcome - We want to successfully add native android code to android bundles and generate apk afterwards.

Please add your build.gradle files to better help solve your issue
